# If a Jew wears Tefillin before Alot HaShahar is it valid B’dieved

Tags: halacha, tefilin, zemanim, orach-chaim, morning-day

According to Halacha, if a Jew wears Tefillin before Alot HaShahar, is it valid B’dieved? Or does it not fill that day’s obligation at all even after the fact?

Comment: https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Putting_On_and_Removing_Tefillin#Earliest_Time